# Not Receiving BOOT_COMPLETED Broad Cast after few days

Tags: android

I am developing a tracking application and i want it to get auto start on Boot completed. My application is working fine for few days. After 8 to 9 days it does not receive boot completed broadcast. Android Manifest is as follows-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
android:versionCode="21"
android:versionName="6.4.1" > 

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />/
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>


<application
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".TrackingApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="TrackingProcess" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TrackingProcess"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".NotificationDialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>

    <service
        android:name=".TrackingService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

BootUpReceiver onReceive is As-

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, TrackingProcess.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

TrackingProccess Is as follows-

```
public class TrackingProcess extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startService(new Intent(this, TrackingService.class));
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.